# Using a conditional Split-Path in a profile prompt

Tags: conditional-statements, prompt, powershell-4.0

I'm using the Prompt function to use a custom prompt. I've got it so I get the date, current working directory and number of objects. Where I am in the `$scripts` or `$modules` locations, I'd like the current working directory to truncate.

```bsh
$scripts = "$(Split-Path $profile)\Scripts"
$modules = "$(Split-Path $profile)\Modules"
```

where the part of the Prompt function responsible is this:

```bsh
Write-Host ($PWD) -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Gray
```

Comment: *I'd like the current working directory to truncate* Truncate to what? What is your current output, and what would you like the output to look like?

Comment: I'd like the truncation to remove the Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell part that prefixes scripts or modules

Comment: Please show your expected and actual output.

Comment: What I get is: C:\Users\max.russell\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts but If I am in that directory, I just want something like ~\scripts

Comment: Then why not just define the variables like this: `$scripts = '~\scripts'`?

Comment: that would certainly provide the truncation, but I'm having an issue with fitting the conditional into the function Prompt - e.g. if the current directory is scripts or module, then truncate otherwise display full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
$basedir = Split-Path $profile
$pattern = [regex]::Escape($basedir) + '\\(Scripts|Modules)(\\.*|$)'
$path = if ($PWD.Path -match $pattern) {
    $PWD.Path.Replace($basedir, '~')
} else {
    $PWD.Path
}
Write-Host $path -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Gray
```

or like this:

```
$pattern = [regex]::Escape((Split-Path $profile)) + '\\((Scripts|Modules)(\\.*|$))'
Write-Host ($PWD.Path -replace $pattern, '~\$1') -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Gray
```

Comment: bingo. Excellent.